# Django update field

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to learn Django so I am pretty much a noob.

I have been trying to do the following simple task for two hours now. I know I have the wrong syntax, but searching Google & SO has not helped me, so I need some advice.

I am trying to update a db field from a Django template, but I need help in understanding how to update the **language_code_disabled** in my **LanguageVersions** views.py code below.

Here is my models.py file code:

```
class LanguageVersion(models.Model):
    """Language version selection for a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    language_code_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.language_code)
```

Here is my views.py code:

```
@login_required
def language_versions_enable(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        language_version = LanguageVersion.objects.get(pk=language_version_id, user=request.user)
    # don't enable Language Version for currently selected language preference.
    if language_version.language_code != request.user.userprofile.language_preference:
        if language_version.language_code_disabled == True:
            # if the users Language Version is disabled, enable the disabled Language Version.
            LanguageVersion.language_code_disabled = False  # THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE I DO NOT UNDERSTAND HOW TO WRITE!
            messages.success(request,_('successfully enabled.'))
    return redirect('language_versions')
```

Excuse the simple question, but I am unable to get this correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update field in the instance (not in the class) and call `save()` method of this instance.

```
language_version.language_code_disabled = False
language_version.save()
```

Comment: catavaran - Thanks. I can see the error I was making. I see now that I must call the save(). I thought that this was done automatically. Now I know better.